# Singleton pattern in Swift 1.2

Tags: swift

I have previously used the following singleton pattern:

```
class Singleton {
    class var sharedInstance : Singleton {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : Singleton = Singleton()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }   
}
```

When the new Xcode beta with Swift 1.2 was released I wanted to try out the new static class properties and methods. So I tried something similar to this:

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance : Singleton = Singleton()
}
```

Looking at the debugger while using this it seems like a lot of nested instances of the singleton class are created by the class constant:

[image: Screenshot of debugger]

But looking thru the allocations it seems that only one instance are created. I guess that means it's working correctly, but I'm not seeing the same behavior with the first pattern.

Comment: The second one seemed to work for me

Comment: If you set a breakpoint somewhere after the class constant is initialized, doesn't it seem like there are multiple instances of the class on the stack?

Comment: I set a variable on the shared instance using the second method in one view controller and after calling `Singleton.sharedInstance.foo` in a second view controller, it successfully recalled the singleton's value for that property

Comment: Yes that works as expected. The problem I'm having is that more than one instance of the class is created.

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior, I'm seeing exactly what one would expect.  If you expand the stack window horizontally, you'll see that there's a handful of different wrapper functions that get called (allocation, initializer, etc., but it looks to me as if only one item is being create and initialized.  And it's all in an instance of "swift_once"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening here is that LLDB is showing to you the static data as if it was instance data.

Because it's static data, it does not exist "in the instance" the way normal instance data works, which causes LLDB to read memory that it should not and present it to you as if it was valid.

In general, the debugger should not show static data inside instances (compare the equivalent C++ and the way LLDB represents it).

Comment: That explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can verify in [swift 1.2 single ton implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80246/swift-1-2-singleton-implementation) that your code is correct.
It's not necesary to declare Singleton.

static let sharedInstance = Singleton()